# Generate graph image with same dimensions/resolution as RStudio graph window

Tags: r, graph, rstudio

I am trying to output a graph image with the same resolution as the graph window in RStudio, and I keep failing. Here is the code I am using:

```
# Leading edge arrival times
#tiff(file = "LEAT.tiff", width = 6400, height = 3200, units = "px", res = 400)
#Cairo(file="LEAT.png", type="png", units="in", width=4, height=3, pointsize=12, dpi=20)
#jpeg("LEAT.jpeg", width = 4, height = 3, units = 'in', res = 1200)
#tiff("LEAT.tiff", width = 4, height = 3, units = 'in', res = 600)
LEAT <- hist(data)
plot(LEAT, 
     col= "darkblue", 
     xlim=c(0,30), 
     main="Leading Edge Arrival Times", 
     xlab="Hours", 
     ylab="Frequency")  
mtext("(Using predicted 90th percentile streamflow)", side=3)
#dev.off()
```

Here is the image if I simply export from the RStudio window (with the dimensions set by how I have the window sized):

[image]

Here is the image using the jpeg function:
(`#jpeg("LEAT.jpeg", width = 4, height = 3, units = 'in', res = 1200)`)

[image]

How can I set anyone of these graph import/creation functions to produce a similar graph?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but man it took a lot of trial and error:

```
tiff("LEAT_2.tiff", width = 800, height = 600, units = 'px')
LEAT <- hist(data)
plot(LEAT, 
     col= "darkblue", 
     xlim=c(0,30), 
     main="Leading Edge Arrival Times", 
     xlab="Hours", 
     ylab="Frequency")  
mtext("(Using predicted 90th percentile streamflow)", side=3)
dev.off()
```

Image:

[image]